# Python: storing a large matrix into a text file for later usage

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array

In your experience, what's the best way to store a 2-dimensional array into a text file? My matrix is pretty huge, but let's use a small 3 x 3 matrix as an example. One could store it, quite literally, like this (to the .txt file):

```
3 7 5
2 9 8
8 0 1
```

with a space between elements of the same row, and a newline character to separate the rows themselves from each other. And then if you want to use this saved matrix with a different python file, you'd just parse accordingly.

However, is there a much better (for instance, a way that requires few lines of code) way to store and retrieve a large matrix?

[EDIT]: Right, now I have a list of lists (or, an array of arrays), but I'm open to the idea of using numpy if that makes things a lot easier

Comment: You say "2-dimensional array" and "matrix"; are you using `numpy`, or do you really have a list of lists?

Comment: Indent the numbers with four spaces to format as code. This is as easy as selecting the relevant text and clicking the `{}` button in the editor.

Comment: @DSM I edited the question, to answer your question

Comment: Note: `list` and `array` aren't synonyms in Python.  `list` is a built-in type; there's an `array.array` type, also built in; and there's `numpy.ndarray`, also often called `array`.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a simple array of arrays, one option is to store it as json with `json.dump(open('file.dat', 'w'))` and load it with `json.load(open('file.dat'))`. This has its pros and cons. (Readable, but not the most efficient.)

If using numpy is an option, you should use it. It's much more efficient at holding, representing and serializing large arrays.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [numpy](http://www.numpy.org), there are [several routines listed under the io category](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.io.html) that should help. An example of one of them follows:

```
>>> """ Assuming your matrix is called x """
>>> from tempfile import TemporaryFile
>>> outfile = TemporaryFile()
>>> np.save(outfile, x)
```

To reload this, you need the load function:

```
>>> x2 = np.load(outfile)
```

And your array should be copied into x2.

An example of [creating a numpy array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.creation.html) from a 2-dimensional python array is the following:

```
x = np.array([2, 3, 1, 0])
```

If you need further help, do leave a comment.

Comment: So I'm guessing you would initialize 'x' as a numpy matrix, or would you do it the naive way by just creating an array of arrays?

Comment: Please see the edit of my answer for assistance in creating the correct structure...

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the [csv module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html):

```
import csv

l = [[3,7,5],
     [2,9,8],
     [8,0,1]]

with open('matrix.txt', 'wb') as csvfile:
    matrixwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
    for row in l:
        matrixwriter.writerow(row)


l2 = []
with open('matrix.txt', 'rb') as csvfile:
    matrixreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
    for row in matrixreader:
        l2.append(row)

print(l2)
```

Comment: would you say this is better than using the numpy method?

Comment: The csv module is part of the Python Standard Library and numpy isn't. Whether that matters to you depends on just where you'll be using it.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would use joblib for storing binary representation of arrays.  It also allows for the use of a `compress` argument to cut down on size.

```
from joblib import dump
dump(arr, filename, compress=3)
```